# Limit of a sum of two variables

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Recently at my calculus course we are doing derivatives and integrals.

I've stumbled upon a sum that seems to have nothing in common with our current objectives, though I'm sure it does have, but still I have no idea how to solve it.

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{4n - \frac{k^2}{n}} $$

I tried to represent it as a $$ f_{n}(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{x}{4n - \frac{k^2}{n}}$$ and to resolve it at a point $x = 1$, but I failed because of the two variables instead of one.

EDIT:

Of course, I would like to get some CLUES how to solve it, not the whole solution.

Comment: "Integrals" Try to recognise a Riemann sum there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This would definitely help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that we have
$$
\int_0^1\frac1{4-x^2}dx=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{4-\frac{k^2}{n^2}}
$$
by definition of the integral.

Comment: But that integral evaluates to $\frac18\ln\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)$. Yet the sum has $n$ terms, each of which is at least $\frac{1}{4n}$ so the sum must be at least $\frac{1}{4}$, which is bigger than $\frac18\ln\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)$. Where is the discrepancy???

Answer (score 1):

Just factor $n$ in the denominator of the sum so one gets

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{4n - \frac{k^2}{n}} =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{4-\frac{k^2}{n^2}}$$

And the RHS is a Riemann sum whose limit is $\int\limits_{0}^1\frac{dx}{4-x^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Take $n$ common from the denominator (I will clear formatting later forgive me)

To get $$ 1/(4-(k^2/n^2)).(1/n) $$
Inside the Σ 
Then treat $ k/n$ as $x $ and $ 1/n $ as $dx $ and replace sigma with integral sign

Obtain the limits by taking upper and lower bound of $x$. Comes out to be 1 and 0. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: If there's any doubt please ask sorry about poor formatting ( I'm working on a mobile device)